# I would like to remove the login pop up from the checkout(Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, checkout, modal

I would like to  remove the login pop up from the checkout:

The login appears on the checkout page(like this)[image]

I wanna remove this option from the checkout page.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You mean you want to remove the login pop up from the checkout?

Comment: yes remove login pop up and show just  a login div in checkout page

Comment: Cool, just posted the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Create a new file checkout_index_index.xml in following path  `app/design/frontend/[package_name]/[your_theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/`

Then add the following code to this new created file.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="authentication" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

After that clear cache using this command.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```